# Can a JSON Validator inspect candidate json for type definitions to validate itself?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a DML that supports custom structures like "customType1" below and which can be used for defining the type of a list of properties:

```
{
 "types": {
    "customType1" : {
      "var1" : "string",
      "var2" : "int"
    }
    .
    .
    .
 },
 "properties": {
   "prop1" : {
     "type": "customType1",
     "value": {
     "var1" : "Hello",
     "var2" : 123
    },
   "prop2" : {
     "type" : "String",
     "value" : "www.google.com"
    }
    .
    .
    .
 }
}
```

Is it possible to write a JSON Schema that can evaluate `prop1`to validate it against the structure defined in `customType1`? The description of custom types specified in `types` would not be known *a priori*, only at the time of evaluation.

If this is beyond the capabilities of the JSON Schema specification, any other suggestions for how to validate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a JSON reference:

```
{
 "types": {
    "customType1" : {
      "var1" : "string",
      "var2" : "int"
    }
    .
    .
    .
 },
 "properties": {
   "prop1" : {
     "$ref" : "#/types/customType1"
    },
   "prop2" : {
     "type" : "String",
     "value" : "www.google.com"
    }
    .
    .
    .
 }
}
```

it is a "pointer" denoting the place of the property schema.

(Note: in JSON Schema we mostly use the key "definitions" instead of "types" by convention).

Comment: in this DML, the JSON that is going to be validated by the schema contains the definition which is then used at other places in the same json. It is not known before hand what "types" will be defined and so the schema I write cannot directly access it

Comment: What I added in the question is a sample JSON, not an attempt at a schema!